# Meaning of "Räumgitter"

Tags: meaning

From Der Spiegel:

> Unstrittig ist, dass in den Hinterhöfen des MfS und der Volkspolizei gepanzerte Wagen mit Schusswaffen bereitstehen; dass am Hauptbahnhof sechs LkW mit **Räumgittern** postiert werden, ...

The word **Räumgitter** cannot be found in any of the dictionaries [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/r%C3%A4umgitter), [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=r%C3%A4umgitter), or [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/r%C3%A4umgitter). The similar word suggested, Raumgitter, refers to some chemical structure and is thus unrelated. From my Google search, "Räumgitter" is some vehicle related to military, but I can't find a good reference. What does the word mean?

Comment: Many German compound words are not to be found in dictionaries, you have to look them up by their constituents – in this case _räumen_ and _Gitter_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a picture of one:

[image]

It is a `Gitter` (grate, grille...) in front of a car. It can be used to clear/evacuate (`räumen`) an area.

The picture can be found here: http://www.panzerbaer.de/helper/bgs_sonderwagen-a.htm

There is another [Spiegel article from 1989](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-13498614.html):

> Die so harmlos als "Zaunsegmente" deklarierten Werkstücke entpuppten sich als Räumgitter für die Lastwagen der Volkspolizei vom Typ "W 50", ...

In 1975 the Räumgitter is also mentioned in another [Spiegel article](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-41471327.html) (this time West Germany):

> setzte die Polizei ein Arsenal neuer Waffen gegen die Demonstranten ein: so ein "Sonderfahrzeug mit ausklappbarem Räumgitter", das geeignet ist, "auch größere Menschenansammlungen wegzuschieben"

It seems, the [Swiss police](http://bos-fahrzeuge.info/einsatzfahrzeuge/37964/Zuerich_-_KaPo_-_Ordnungsdienstfahrzeug/photo/37964) has also a car with a `Räumgitter`

Answer (score 1):

A **Räumgitter** is a kind of attachment placed on the front of a vehicle (in the text you've included, onto a large truck), which is usually employed as a moving barricade. The attachment is made of a metal lattice.

As far as an English equivalent, that's likely technical jargon. The train equivalent seen on steam engines is called a pilot, however this attachment is probably referred to as a "grate barricade" or something similar.